# Group items and delete some of them

Tags: c#, linq

I have a following list item and I want to remove the class where `ClassName` and `StartDate` are same. I want to remove the item where `Status` is "Old".

```
CourseId    ClassName    StartDate    Status
--------    --------      --------   ---------
12321       Math         08-25-2017    New
14321       Math         08-25-2017    Old
13221       Math         08-25-2017    Old
32342       Physics      08-25-2017    New
34345       Math         08-25-2017    New
25325       Math         01-25-2018    New
45329       Math         01-25-2018    Old 
33325       Chemistry    01-25-2018    New      
44345       Chemistry    01-25-2018    Old
```

For example, in the following there are two math course start dates are same but I want to delete the second and third one since status are old, and want to keep the first one, status is new.

```
12321       Math         08-25-2017    New
14321       Math         08-25-2017    Old
13221       Math         08-25-2017    Old
```

Trying to group them based on date and classname as follows, But I am stuck how to delete items from each group.

```
List<Course> courses  = allCourses
.Where()
.OrderByDescending(x=> x.StartDate)
.GroupBy(x => x.StartDate && x.ClassName)
.FirstOrDefault()?.ToList()
```

Comment: LINQ is about querying, so you don't delete items, you include the ones you want in the answer.

Comment: I do not know how I can delete?

Comment: `distinct` will remove duplicates

Comment: @NetMage, LINQ is about a pipeline of functions. `where` deletes, `distinct` deletes

Comment: @pm100 I would not call that deletion, but rather selection. And I know how LINQ works :)

Comment: You have another Math class with the same start date that is also New - 34345 - how do you expect that to be handled? NOTE that your `GroupBy` is wrong - it won't compile due to type errors (you can't apply `&&` operator to types `DateTime` and `String`).

Comment: `.Where(z => z.Status == "New")` and likely `.GroupBy(x => new { x.StartDate, x.ClassName })`.

Comment: If there is one "Old" course, do you want to keep that one course in the answer? Or do you just want new courses in the answer?

Comment: @mjwills That would depend on how multiple "New" courses on the same `StartDate` are to be handled.

Answer (score 0):

Since your original data has multiple "New" items possible in a group, I selected all "New" items.

First you group by `StartDate` and `ClassName`. Note the proper syntax to group on multiple values is to create an anonymous object.

Then you order the results - order before the group by can't be assumed to work.

Then for each resulting group, you select all the courses with a "New" status if there is more than one course, otherwise you take the one course.

```
var courses = allCourses.GroupBy(c => new { c.StartDate, c.ClassName })
                        .OrderByDescending(cg => cg.Key.StartDate)
                        .SelectMany(cg => cg.Where(c => cg.Count() == 1 || c.Status == "New").Select(c => new { c.CourseId, cg.Key.ClassName, cg.Key.StartDate, c.Status }));
```

Comment: Would it make sense to do the `Where` before the `GroupBy`?

Comment: @mjwills I assumed from the (vague) description that if a course had no duplicates, you want to keep the one course regardless of status.